# Android OpenGL move shapes separately

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new in OpenGL, and I'd like to ask you for help or even code example (I went through many pages but it seems I'm too fresh to find proper answer or ask a valid question).

My use case is: create 3 triangles and allow user to move each of them by finger in different place on the screen (like drag&drop)

Inside renderer I keep my triangle objects:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    ArrayList<MyTriangle> myObjectsOnSurface_;
}
```

But how can I determine which object should I move from onTouchEvent(..) ?

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent evt) {
        float currentX = evt.getX();
        float currentY = evt.getY();

        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to maintain a data-structure of the center point (x,y) of each triangle, then on a touch event determine whether any center point is near the touch point.  Only move a triangle if the euclidian distance from touch (x,y) to its center point (x,y) is acceptable. 2D distance == sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2).   This process is out of scope of OpenGL calls, so rolling your own solution sounds reasonable.